# I am using nextauth with credentails for authentication purpose. sometimes The email and password gets appended to url and the page reloads at /login

Tags: reactjs, next.js, formik, next-auth

when the network is slow, the email and password is appended to a url and page reloads at the url changes from http://localhost:3000/login?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2FprotectedRoute to http://localhost:3000/login?email=user%40aabs@gmail.com&password=1234
I am using next.auth in next.js, using credentails. I keep running to the above case. it is mostly when user first visit the site and has slow connection. I am usign formik for the form and on submit function

```
type Props = {
  callbackUrl: string
};

export default function LoginForm({ callbackUrl }: Props) {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        email: "",
        password: "",
      }}
      onSubmit={async (values, { setErrors }) => {
        const res = await signIn("credentials", {
          callbackUrl: callbackUrl,
          redirect: true,
          email: values.email,
          password: values.password,
        });

        if (res?.error) {
          switch (res.error) {
            case "fetch failed":
              toast.error("Cannot login - Check your internet connection");
              break;
            default:
              setErrors({
                password: "Invalid email and/or password",
              });
          }
        } else {
          router.push(res?.url ?? "/");
        }
      }}
    >
      {(props) => (
        <Form className="flex flex-col pt-6 w-full items-center">
          ....
          <div className="mt-2 text-sm text-indigo-700">
            <Link href="/forgot-password">Forgot Password?</Link>
          </div>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}
```

I tried setting redirect:true so that it gets redirected upon authentication. this won't solve the issue of appending email and password to the url.